# Why does MongoDB sort return empty names for ascending sorted documents?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have a simple collection of restaurants (from MongoDB documentation). One of the fields is “name”. I can easily find all the names of the restaurants as follows:

```
db.restaurants.find({}, {"name" : 1, "_id" : 0});
```

If I try to sort by descending order, i.e.,

```
db.restaurants.find({}, {"name" : 1, "_id" : 0}).sort({"name":-1});
```

everything comes out fine:

```
{ "name" : "Zz'S Pizza & Grill" }
{ "name" : "Zz Clam Bar" }
...
```

However, if I try to sort by ascending order:

```
db.restaurants.find({}, {"name" : 1, "_id" : 0}).sort({"name":1});
```

I get

```
{ "name" : "" }
{ "name" : "" }
...
```

What's odd is that if I add other keys to the sort argument before "name", it then does the ascending sort properly, i.e.

```
db.restaurants.find({}, {"name" : 1, "_id" : 0}).sort({"cuisine":1, "name":1});
```

What gives? Thanks for any insights!

Comment: Because `""` is less than `"a"`. You were expecting something else? I think you will find the compound sort is actually "exactly" the same. I would suggest an issue here is that the field has empty strings, and instead it probably should rather have no property at all. But then again `null` also has it's own sort preference.

Comment: I am an idiot, I didn't see it was an iterator and there were more results. I didn't realize my set had entries with null names. Duh! Thank you!